# Getting script5007: object expected error on Edge on a simple API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, microsoft-edge

I have a simple API call in a React component, which is done when I click the button. While this is happening, the button has a spinner put in it's place, and once I get a response, it is supposed to go back to normal.

This is all swell in most browsers, except edge, where the spinner hangs and I get the following error message:

> script5007: object expected

Keep in mind that if I look in the network tab, the PATCH request is completed and if I update the page, it does update as expected. So I don't know whats going on and no similar questions relating to that error have been helpful.

Here is roughly my code:

```
export default class MyComponent {
  handleClick (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault()

      this.setTogglingButtonStatus(true) // note, this is a reactive variable handled elsewhere
      doPatchRequest(something).then(null, Errors.alert).always(() => {
        // The code hangs despite the PATCH having finished and I never get to this point
        console.warn('request ended!')
        this.setTogglingButtonStatus(false)
      })
    }

  render () {
    return (
      <button onClick={(evt) => this.handleClick(evt)} disabled={togglingStatus}>My button</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: should have specified the line where the error allegedly happens, it says in the console that it is on `this.setTogglingButtonStatus(true)`, but if I step through it it runs normally and only appears after the request has been completed. So I am left quite confused...

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: If you google that error message you'll see that there are many possible causes, it's hard to tell what the actual problem is from the tiny snippet you've provided.

Comment: You're missing quotes here: `console.warn(request ended!)`. That's obviousy not the actual code, you would get a syntax error.

Comment: Regarding the `console.warn`: Oops... Yeah, that was something I just added for the example, it's not in the actual code.

Comment: And I did just notice that the error is actually happening on `this.setTogglingButtonStatus(true)`, so the original premise of the question is in fact incorrect.

Comment: What is `Errors.alert`?

Comment: It is an Error object. Basically how we will display the error. However,  it isn't relevant for this error (it still happens even if I remove it)